# how to specify Header and footer of excel file using VB.net code?

Tags: vb.net, excel

I can specify cell values using  VB.net code like this:

```
      xlWorkSheet.Range("A1").Value = "Results"
```

How can i specify the header and footer of the excel sheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this will do

`xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader = "Your text"`

**You can use Left/Center/Right Header/Footer.**